Cannot boot after installing xen-hypervisor-amd64
I installed ubuntu 20 (using existing pxeboot; cannot boot from USB. 20 was easy to install, 24; not so much), immediately do-release-upgrade to 22, and again to 24.
Hardware: Dell Poweredge R730xd with 2x Xeon E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50 GHz (48t/24c), 368 GB RAM. Configured the raid controller for raid0 2x 200 GB SSD (/dev/sda) and raid6 20x 1.2TB 2.5" SAS drives (/dev/sdb). oh, and two NVME that were not detected at install (20 is probably too old).
While /dev/sdb was present at install time, I never created any lvm volumes on it, so it's unused at this time. the NVME drives (not seen by the raid controller) are also unconfigured/unused.
Installed with lvm for root single-partition /dev/mapper/vgsandstone-root
system boots ok on this config, but after apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64 , all attempts to boot into the hypervisor (dom0) fail. It drops me into the initramfs prompt which to be honest I've never had to do before in all my decades.
I see that /dev/nvme* devices are present
I noticed that /dev/sd[ab] are missing, which I presume is the source of my problem.
lvm doesn't show anything (probably because /dev/sd[ab] are missing)
modprobe megaraid_sas runs, but /dev/sd? don't appear, and vgchange -ay effects no changes.
I can use Grub to boot to the regular Ubuntu Server (no hypervisor), and that works fine.
The strange thing is that both configurations point at the same initramfs, so what could be wrong here? I've installed the xen hypervisor before on 18, 20, and 22 without issue on similar hardware (only difference is slightly different cpu Xeon E5-2640 v3 @ 2.6 GHz with 32t/16c (fewer) and less ram and fewer HDDs)
What can I add to assist with debugging?

CONCLUSION: ubuntu 24 with Xen hypervisor kernel is broken on Dell Poweredge R730xd.
WORKAROUND: I reinstalled to ubuntu 22, which works fine.
